# Append code before phone number if call is made from SIM2

Tags: calls, huawei, dual-sim

I've been trying to find a way to do this for weeks now but I just can't seem to find a solution.
In my phone (Huawei Nova 3) I have two SIM cards, private (SIM1) and work (SIM2). 
SIM2 has a dedicated dialer app which basically appends a specific code (which never changes, 154784) before the number I want to call.

Phone Number: 070-1111-2222
Called from within the app becomes: 1547847011112222

The problem is this dialer only supports SIM2 and currently I have to use two different dialers depending on which SIM card I want to call from.

What I'd like to do is to use the default dialer, which prompts me to choose a SIM card whenever I want to make a call and make it so that it automatically appends the code above (154784) if I choose SIM2. I would like to avoid using the other dialer app altogether.

Is it something that can be done or should I just give up on it?

Comment: AFAIK dual sim is not a feature of standard Android AOSP (please correct me if I am wrong). Therefore there is no general answer for that and the two-dialer solution is manufacturer specific. As you conceal your device manufacturer and device name there is nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your input and sorry about the missing information. I have a Huawei Nova 3 running Android 9. I could upload a couple of screenshots to better illustrate my question but I'm not sure it's allowed.